# C# ABCPdf out of memory exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, abcpdf

I have a problem regarding with the use of abcpdf which errors when adding around 70 mb file size of html (this size is not static it may increase or decrease, **however**, if file size or the data inside the **html is small**, it will work) using the AddImageUrl function. I am using v10 of abcpdf and also uses the using block around the doc function e.g.
    using(var doc = new Doc){}

The error is a out of memory exception when adding the html to AddImageUrl, has anyone encountered this error? I have tried setting the timeout and retries into a bigger number, creating a delegate async method (using 2010), it has no use.

Can anyone help me with this one? Thanks!

PS: I am using vs 2010 for now, though we're currently on upgrade to 2017.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't AbcPDF work by simply repackaging QtPDF or wkhtmltopdf? If so, is it a CLR-rasied `OutOfMemoryException`, or one raised by GDI, or one raised by their external process wrapper (as QtPDF and wkhtmltopdf run out-of-process)?

Comment: @Dai Hi, I can assume that it is not a CLR-raised nor the GDI, but maybe the AbcPDF wrapper itself. Though, I am sorry but I am not sure about the abcPDF if the wrapper of it is QtPDF or wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: @Dai abcpdf has absolutely, positively no connection to QtPDF, wkhtmltopdf, or any other wrapper. They wrote their own PDF engine, beginning over a decade ago.